# Solidify adds curved ridge - How to get rid of it

Tags: modifiers

I need to solidify the hole's edge into the fish.

I tried complex, simple and some other options in the modifier, yet I can't get a clean falloff from the outside into the hole.

[image: pic]

**Video GIF 7s:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pf6i.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. select edge loop
2. <kbd>E</kbd> -> <kbd>S</kbd>
3. select edge loop (faces)

[image]

4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> -> extrude along normals

then you get:

[image]